# How to use ActiveMQ::commands::ActiveMQMapMessage

Tags: c++, activemq-classic

So far the `Session` object created through `Connection Factory` has the option to get `MapMessage` defined in `cms/MapMessage.h`. However, I need to use `ActiveMQMapMessage` which is defined in `activemq::commands::ActiveMQMessage`.

I am not able to figure out how to get this map message. I tried looking at activemq cpp documentation but could not get any help.

Comment: Why do you need to use the actual ActiveMQMapMessage type instead of the MapMessage interface.

Comment: The `consumer` of the message requires `Group ID` of the message. The option to enable GroupID is availabe only in the `activemq::commands` namespace

Comment: and this message->getStringProperty("JMSXGroupID"); doesn't work?

Comment: After doing a grep on the activemq cpp library I was able to find the correct way to set the groupID. Thanks for the suggestion !